# Excel worksheet multi-criteria function (like Index-Match array) to fetch last value of an item, looking up by item name and date

Tags: arrays, excel, function, indexing, match

I'm sharing a sample table with list of products with prices that are updated over time. I have an Index-Match array function that can look up price of a product for a given month. But what I want is a function that will get the last entered value for a product. So the function should search for product name, and from the date column go to the last date where there's a record for that product and fetch price for that row. Not all products are updated in all months, so can't just go for last date. Different products will have different last dates. (E.g. in Current calculator only one product #3333 has entry for 5/1/22 so other two show #N/A. Which is fine. No need to adjust that calculator. It's just an example)

I'm using this formula in current calculator, cell F5 (as in image):

> =INDEX($C$4:$C$12, MATCH(1,(E5=$B$4:$B$12)*($G$4=$A$4:$A$12),0))

[image: Sample table. Current calculator with 2 examples. Desired calculator output.]

Comment: Please do not add answers from the answer spots below to the question.  As the originator of the question, you mark the answer you use as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It will mark this question as resolved.  I have reset you question back to the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,E12,A:A,MAXIFS(A:A,B:B,E12))
```

It will return the value at the last date where the product number matches.